# What is the error in this computation of matrix determinant?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I'm trying to find determinant of 4x4 matrix, It gets compiled, takes the values for matrix and then suddenly terminates showing some unknown error caused it to stop working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int detcalfnl(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int anss;
    anss = ((a*d)-(b*c));
    return anss;
}
/*********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
void detcalthree(int mat[3][3],int *ansss)
{
   *ansss=0;
   int x;
   for(x=0;x<3;x++)
       {
           if(x==0)
           {
            *ansss+=((mat[0][x])*(detcalfnl(mat[x+1][x+1],mat[x+1][x+2],mat[x+2][x+1],mat[x+2][x+2])));
           }
           else if(x==1)
           {
            *ansss+=((-1)*((mat[0][x])*(detcalfnl(mat[x][x-1],mat[x][x+1],mat[x+1][x-1],mat[x+1][x+1]))));
           }
           else if(x==2)
           {
            *ansss+=((mat[0][x])*(detcalfnl(mat[x-1][x-2],mat[x-1][x-1],mat[x][x-2],mat[x][x-1])));
           }
       }
   }
/*********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
void detcalfour(int mat[4][4],int *ansss)
{
   *ansss=0;
   int a1[3][3],a2[3][3],a3[3][3],a4[3][3];
   int x,row,clm,a5,a6,a7,a8;
   int *p5=&a5;
   int *p6=&a6;
   int *p7=&a7;
   int *p8=&a8;

    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        for(row=1;row<4;row++)
        {
            for(clm=0;clm<4;clm++)
            {
                if(clm==x){continue;}
                else
                    {
                if(x==0)
                {
                    a1[b][a]=mat[row][clm];
                }
                else if(x==1)
                {
                    a2[b][a]=mat[row][clm];
                }
                else if(x==2)
                {
                    a3[b][a]=mat[row][clm];
                }
                else if(x==3)
                {
                    a4[b][a]=mat[row][clm];
                }
                }
                a++;
            }
            b++;
        }
    }
    detcalthree(a1,p5);
    detcalthree(a2,p6);
    detcalthree(a3,p7);
    detcalthree(a4,p8);
    *ansss=((mat[0][0])*(*p5))-((mat[0][1])*(*p6))+((mat[0][2])*(*p7))-((mat[0][3])*(*p8));
   }
/*********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
int main()
{
     int dim,row,clm,fnlans;

    printf("Please Enter The Dimension Of Matrix :");
    scanf("%d",&dim);
    printf("\n\n\n");
     int oprnd[dim][dim];

    for(row=0;row<dim;row++)
    {
        for(clm=0;clm<dim;clm++)
        {
            printf("\nPlease Provide Element For Row %d and Column %d : ",row+1,clm+1);
            scanf("%d",&oprnd[row][clm]);
        }
    }
 int *pfs=&fnlans;
 detcalfour(oprnd,pfs);
    printf("\n\n\nValue Of Determinant Is %d \n\n",*pfs);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should put a clear title, focusing on the question. And you should learn how to debug, since the problem occurs during the program execution. Also in `for(row=1;row<4;row++)` you're using a 1-based value, while the mat[] is 0-based; change the loop for 0..3.

Answer (score 1):

In `detcal4`, inside the loop on `x`, `a` and `b` are set to zero and `a` is incremented inside the inner loop (on `clm`) using `a++`. This incrementing is repeated even as the outer loop iterates; `a` is never reset to zero. So it increases beyond the array dimensions. This results in the code accessing the arrays `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, and `a4` out of bounds, corrupting memory.

Reset `a` to zero each time the loop on `clm` is started. Move the `int a=0;` from outside the loop on `row` to inside it.

As a matter of good general practice, declare variables just where they are needed. Since `a` is not needed outside the loop on `row`, it should not be declared outside that loop, and declaring it inside automatically avoids this error.

Comment: It started running but not calculating the correct answer, I'm working on that. @eric